# Strange line when trying to use Sliver App Bar

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use an expanded sliver app bar on one of my screens, but am getting an unexpected thin line on the screen. I tried to get rid of it by using a stack with a black container at the bottom, and that worked but the stretch features of the expanded app bar were not working well with the stack. Any better suggestions?

```
SliverAppBar(
              collapsedHeight: 140,
              expandedHeight: 250,
              stretch: true,
              //can use onStretchTrigger to implement refresh on stretch
              backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
              bottom: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                      child: Text(
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        barName,
                        style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
                          fontSize: 60,
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 20,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(25, 25, 25, 1),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(30)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                stretchModes: [
                  StretchMode.zoomBackground,
                  StretchMode.blurBackground
                ],
                background: Image.asset(
                  barImagePath,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  opacity: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(.4),
                ),
                // Stack(
                //   alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                //   children: [
                //     Image.asset(
                //       barImagePath,
                //       width: double.maxFinite,
                //       fit: BoxFit.cover,
                //       opacity: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(.4),
                //     ),
                //     Container(height: 2, color: Color.fromRGBO(25, 25, 25, 1)),
                //   ],
                // ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image: Image of screen]

Comment: what are you using after SliverAppBar

Comment: put full source code.